# Communication between View Controllers in iOS MVVM

Tags: ios, mvvm

I am working on a simple app to try out MVVM in iOS. I have only two screens in the app. `Screen A` displays content and the user can tap on `settings` button to pull up `screen B`. `Screen B` allows the user to change settings which affect the way `screen A` displays the content.

- How should I communicate changes made in `screen B` to `screen A` so that `screen A` can re-display the content based on the setting changes? In MVC, I would use protocols/delegate to communicate changes made in `ViewControllerB` to `ViewControllerA`. Since view controllers have direct access to the models, I can just pass the updated model in the delegate call. In MVVM, would the communication happen between `ViewModelB` to `ViewModelA` or `ViewControllerB` to `ViewControllerA`(like MVC).
- If the communication is happening between view controllers, what is `ViewControllerB` really passing to `ViewControllerA`? `ViewModelA`? If so, doesn't `ViewControllerB` knowing about `ViewModelA` defeat the purpose of reducing view controller responsibility/knowledge?

Thank you for taking time to read the question!

Comment: In my opinion (and I do mean "opinion"), a model class should represent the current shared state within the app.  The view models should communicate with the underlying model to get/set the portion of the state that relates to their view controllers.  In other words, I'm not a fan of passing anything non-trivial between UI-related classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a situation like this, I would engineer the data stream as follows:

1. Both `ViewModelA` and `ViewModelB` communicate with some entity from a model layer (the first M from MVVM). Frequently such entities are called "services" and contain persistence/network logic.
2. When the user opens `ViewControllerB` and changes some settings, `ViewModelB` makes respective changes to the model.
3. `ViewModelA` observes changes to the same model (via KVO, NotificationCenter, reactive publishers or a good old delegate pattern, whatever suits you best) and reacts to them by updating `ViewControllerA` if needed.

This way neither of your view models need to know about each other, and your model layer acts like a single source of truth for both of them.

Comment: Thank you for the response! It makes sense and I definitely like the "single source of truth" philosophy. What about a case when you don't want to store anything in local storage and yet multiple screens are changing the same model? Example: When user is filling out a form over multiple screens. Would you opt for singleton in that case?

Comment: Yes, my personal preference for such case would be to have the view models of these multiple screens work with the same instance of a model. You can achieve that either by using a singleton (which I generally avoid though because it makes unit testing harder) or by injecting the same instance of a service object into the view models (I like using the Coordinator pattern for that, so my MVVM becomes MVVM-C).

Comment: Yeah my preference is to avoid singletons as much as I can as well, so the Coordinator pattern is what I will learn toward in those situations. I have mostly avoided adopting the pattern in the past because it seemed like an overkill for some of my apps, but in some cases it definitely provides an elegant solution over singletons. Thank you for your response! Appreciate it!